# How to send a fixed header value without showing it in Swagger UI?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-6.0

can I add a custom header, and then in the Swagger UI interface the API call is asking this header as a parameter. But I actually just want to send it with the call hardcoded, without the possibility to be changed by the user.

How can this be achieved?

```
/// <summary>
/// A header item for OpenAPI standard
/// </summary>
public class MyCustomTokenHeader : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.Parameters == null)
        {
            operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();
        }

        operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
        {
            Name = "Header-Parameter",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Required = false,
            
            Example = new OpenApiString("my-default-header-value")
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a _request interceptor_ to mutate outgoing requests. There's an example in Swashbuckle docs: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#use-client-side-request-and-response-interceptors

Answer (score -1):

I tried to find a property which could make the custom header value to be disabled so that users couldn't change it, or make it invisible, but according to the properties for this parameter, we don't have such a feature.

[image]

So I think we could use custom swagger UI as a workaround. We could create `wwwroot/swagger/ui` folder and create `custom.css` file. Inside it we could add style like `.parameters {display: none;}`. Then [inject this custom css](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#customize-the-ui) file in Program.cs.

```
app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.InjectStylesheet("/swagger/ui/custom.css");
    });
```